# How do I translate the word "groundbreaking"?

Tags: traducción

As in a "groundbreaking hunting ban". I think it would be:

> prohibición del ... pionero

Alternatives I'm finding are

> prohibición del ... revolucionario
>
> prohibición del ... innovador

Comment: Depends on your phrase. An example may be: _Prohiben **por la primera vez** la caza del urogallo durante todo el año_ (I've made this up). Or: _**Como nunca antes** prohiben la caza de la perdiz en el mes de diciembre_

Comment: In your example _pionero,_  _revolucionario_ or _innovador_ qualify _prohibición,_ that is a feminine noun, so you should use _pionera,_ ...

Comment: I would analyze what ground exactly is being broken, and then spell it out: Tal prohibición abre camino a ______, por ejemplo, un nuevo método de redactar una ley etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundbreaking) define *groundbreaking* como

> The term groundbreaking, when used as an adjective, may mean **being or making something that has never been done, seen, or made before**.

El [traductor de Google](https://translate.google.com) lo traduce como

> innovador <sub>(masculino)</sub>, innovadora <sub>(femenino)</sub>

El diccionario [WordMagic](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/en-es/groundbreaking.php) ofrece, además, otras posibilidades:

> - de avanzada
> - innovador
> - pionero
> - precursor
> - que marca un hito
> - transcendental

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it:

> transcendental prohibición de caza / significativa prohibición... / notable prohibición...

I think "transcendental" is the most accurate.